# Future/Promise without waiting for result possible? Return Unit

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I have a question about scala's `Future`.

Currently I have a program that runs through a directory and checks if there is a document.
If there is a file the program should convert these file into a ".pdf"

My Code looks like this (It's pseudocode):

```
for(file <- directory) {
  if(timestamp > filetimestamp) {
    Future {
    // do a convert job that returns UNIT
    }
  }
}
```

Is this valid code or do I need to wait for the return value?

Are there any other alternative's that are as lightweight as Futures?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To convert inside a `Future`, simply use `map` and `flatMap`. The actual operations are performed asynchronously when the callbacks are complete, but they are type safe.

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

for(file <- directory) {
 if(timestamp > filetimestamp) {
   val future = Future {
   // do a convert job that returns UNIT
   } map {
     file => // whatever you want.
   }
}
```

Comment: as i said i don't want to wait until its complete, i just want to let it convert and the for should go to the next file and do the same thing

Comment: hm that looks easy, what do you mean with be aware of what I'm doing / blocking behavior? What could happen? the only thing i'm scared about is the memory consumption

Comment: @ChristianSchmitt About memory, I recall the default Scala IO library doesn't release resources. You got a great replacement from jsuereth, found here: https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm.

Comment: the thing is, currently I use [http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/wordsjava/Home](Aspose.Words) to convert files from doc/docx to PDF (it's a java library) and It takes some time to complete, so i wanted to let the convert task be a little bit more asynchronously. Since I convert 5000 Documents or more and that will take some time. And I'm scared that my heap getting out of memory. since I barley know something about future's.. I mean if I create ~1000 Futures scala will load them all into the heap, right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46688/discussion-between-christian-schmitt-and-flavian)

Comment: There's a small problem here in that if the convert job returns `Unit`, `file` in the map will be `()`. To use the previous `file`, just discard the unit parameter instead with `map { _ => ... }`.

Comment: The other problem is that the usual config ForkJoinPool creates daemon threads, so if your app creates many futures and doesn't wait for anything (future or latch), when main thread terminates, so does the app, before the futures run to completion.

Answer (score 7):

**Warning!**
If any Future throws a "NonFatal" error, it will be swallowed.  This is a serious gotcha when using Future[Unit]: if no code ever evaluates the future, errors can disappear down a black hole.  (It affects any Future[_], but if you are returning a value, you normally do something with it, so the error is discovered.)

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
scala.concurrent.Future { throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo") }

scala> res16: scala.concurrent.Future[Nothing] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@64dd3f78

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
scala.concurrent.Future { throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo"); 42 }

scala> res11: scala.concurrent.Future[Int] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@65c8295b
```

An alternative which accomplishes the same thing, but does not hide the error:

```
scala> val context = scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
context.execute(new Runnable {
  def run() = throw new IllegalArgumentException("foo")
})
context: scala.concurrent.ExecutionContextExecutor = scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl@1fff4cac

scala>      |      | java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: foo
at $line48.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1.run(<console>:34)
at $line48.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$anon$1.run(<console>:33)
at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$3.exec(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:107)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is valid. All the `Future`s you create will be run, and their return values will be discarded and garbage collected.